# What is the name of this mathematical object

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

While i was programming i incountered the following: The set of all subsequences of $A$ that are in the form of $(a_n,a_{n+1},...,a_{n+k}),\ k>0$.
I wanted to know if this kind of subsequences has a name, and if they are useful.

Comment: What is $A$? If $A$ is just a sequence, then $(a_n,a_{n+1},\dots,a_{n+k})$ is known as a [substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring), and also as a consecutive subsequence.

Answer (score 3):

Such objects are called $k+1$-tuples. (For example, if $k=1$ we call them $2$-tuples. It's more common to refer to $n$-tuples viz. $k=n-1$, although that's inconvenient given how you've parameterised the indices.) Construed as subsequences, I suppose you could call it a $k+1$-tuple subsequence, or (if you needn't specify the value of $k$) finite consecutive subsequences. If there is another name for them, your readership probably wouldn't know it, so it's worth sticking with familiar terms.